# What was the origin of the nursery rhyme "Don't care was made to care"?

Tags: folklore, nursery-rhymes

Many a child who has expressed indifference has had the following verse spoken to them:

> Don’t care was made to care,
>   Don’t care was hung:
>   Don’t care was put in a pot
>   And boiled till he was done.

What is its origin?

Comment: My mother (78) just told this to my father (87) over breakfast because he said he did t care if he messed up the crossword puzzle. She and her sisters were told it frequently by her late mother born 1913. Thank you for the background!

Answer (score 5):

Looks like the author is unknown; but its origins appear to be mid-1800s London’s East End. The full rhyme is as follow:

> Don’t care didn’t care,
>   Don’t care was wild:
>   Don’t care stole plum and pear
>   Like any beggar’s child.
>
> Don’t care was made to care,
>   Don’t care was hung:
>   Don’t care was put in a pot
>   And boiled till he was done.

[Don't care didn't care (idea)](https://everything2.com/user/Tem42/writeups/Don%2527t+care+didn%2527t+care)

Comment: Many thanks for this and for that link. So there's a published reference from 1848. I'd love to learn more about the background to the rhyme in London's East End.

Comment: Glad to help! It was cool to see how far back this went. I hope you get more responses!  =)